2 Thes 2:3 Does the apostasy come before the Day or is it the first in a series within the Day?
In 2 Thes 2:2 Paul used the perfect active of ἐνίστημι, which I take to mean they thought they were present in the Day of the Lord (DotL). In verse 3 the verb is missing but the antecedent verb is implied.
My question is concerning the apostasy and the revealing of the Antichrist coming first. Does vs 3 necessarily mean the apostasy and revealing come BEFORE the DotL, or can in mean the apostasy is the FIRST in a series of events that are present WITHIN the DotL?
(2)…ὡς ὅτι ἐνέστηκεν ἡ ἡμέρα τοῦ κυρίου· (3)…ὅτι ἐὰν μὴ ἔλθῃ ἡ ἀποστασία πρῶτον καὶ ἀποκαλυφθῇ ὁ ἄνθρωπος τῆς ἀνομίας…
2 Thessalonians 2 (BLB)

V2 - for you not quickly to be shaken in mind, nor to be troubled, neither by spirit, nor by word, nor by letter as if by us, as that day of the Lord is present (ἐνέστηκεν).
V3 - No one should deceive you in any way, because it is not until the apostasy shall have come first, and the man of lawlessness shall have been revealed--the son of destruction,


Answer
The apostasy comes clearly before the Day of the Lord and is the last in a series of events that usher in the Day of the Lord.
Explanation
First and foremost, the Day of the Lord is not a welcome day!
Don’t desire it! It is gloomy to the extreme!

“Woe to those desiring the day of Jehovah! What is this for you?
The day of Jehovah is darkness, and not light” (Amos 5:18).


“Shall not the day of Jehovah be darkness, and not light; even
very dark, and not any brightness in it?” (verse 20).

It will be a terrifying day; a day of destruction; this time not from man but from God!

“Howl! For the day of Jehovah is at hand. It shall come as a
destruction from the Almighty” (Isa 13:6).


“Alas for the day! For the day of Jehovah is at hand. And it shall
come as a destruction from the Almighty” (Joel 1:15).

And no man will be able to stand it.

“Behold, the day of Jehovah comes, cruel and with wrath and fierce
anger, to lay the land waste” (verse 9).


“For the day of Jehovah is very great and terrifying, and who can
endure it?” (Joel 2:11).


“The great day of Jehovah is near; it is near and rushing greatly, the
sound of the day of Jehovah. The mighty man shall cry out bitterly
there” (Zeph 1:14).

How to Identify the DotL?
It is very easy:

“The sun shall be turned to darkness and the moon to blood,
before the coming of the great and awesome day of Jehovah” (Joel 2:31).


“Behold, the day of Jehovah comes……..For the stars of the heavens
and their constellations shall not give light; the sun shall be
darkened in its going forth, and the moon shall not reflect its
light” (Isa 13:9,10).

This is a very clear signal to know the beginning of the Day of the Lord.
Jesus Christ Identifies
Jesus Christ pinpoints the Day of the Lord:

“And immediately after the affliction of those days the sun
will be darkened and the moon will not give her light, and the
stars will fall from the heaven, and the powers of the heavens will be shaken” (Mat 24:29).

So the “Affliction” known as the “Great Tribulation” or “Jacob’s Trouble” just precedes the start of the Day of the Lord.
Again what signals the start of the Great Tribulation is the Abomination of Desolation placed in the Holy place (there is a warning to the reader; “try to understand”) by the man of sin.

“Then when you see the abomination of desolation, which was
spoken of by Daniel the prophet, standing in the holy place (the one
reading, let him understand)………. For there will be great
affliction, such as has not happened from the beginning of the world
until now, no, nor ever will be. ” (Mat 24:15, 21).

Now, according to Jesus Christ, what immediately precedes the Day of the Lord is the “Affliction/Great Tribulation/Jacob’s Trouble” signaled by the Abomination of Desolation.
Paul Identifies
But according to Paul what precedes “the Day of Christ” is the apostasy.
What happens here?

“and the man of sin is revealed, the son of perdition, the one
opposing and exalting himself over everything being called God, or
object of worship, so as for him "to sit in the temple of God" as God,
setting forth himself, that he is God” (2 Thes 2:3-4).

This is exactly what Prophet Daniel foretold:

“And the king shall do according to his will. And he shall exalt and
magnify himself above every god; he shall even speak marvelous
things against the God of gods and shall prosper until the fury is
completed. For that which is decreed shall be done” (Daniel 11:36).

Wow, this is immediately after the Abomination of Desolation (see verse 31)!
So, Daniel 11:31 talks about the Abomination of Desolation and verse 36 talks about the man of sin magnifying himself above God.
Conclusion
So, the conclusion is sure.
The correct sequence of events according to Prophet Daniel, Lord Jesus Christ and Apostle Paul is this:

Abomination of Desolation;

Apostasy/Affliction/Great Tribulation/Jacob’s Trouble;

Sun, moon, stars darken; and

The Day of Jehovah/the LORD/Christ begins!



Roi. Very good answer. At Matthew 24:3 the disciples ask Jesus, "What will be the sign of your coming, and of the end/consummation/end of the world." Jesus explains from vs4-14 the problems the world is facing. At vs15 is the "tipoff" that when you see the antichrist standing in the temple, it's time to get out of Dodge from vs16-28. Vs29 states, "After the tribulation Jesus and His angels come for the elect, vs31. Paul backs this up at 2 Thess 1:3 when he says the elect get "rest/relief" when Jesus is revealed from heaven etc. As a side note, I don't see a rapture before these events.

Thank you very much Mr. Bond, for your appreciation and upvote.

The answer to this is quite simple about what Paul is saying in 2 Thess 2.
First, notice that Paul uses "coming of our Lord Jesus Christ" (V1) as a synonym for "the Day of the Lord" (V2); ie, both phrases mean the same thing.
Second, Paul's instruction boils down to this - some were evidently suggesting that Jesus had already returned, ie, had already come.  However, Paul says to ignore any such false message because:

the day of the Lord will not occur before "the rebellion" (V3) occurs
the man of lawlessness = the "son of destruction" is revealed
he will exalt himself as the ultimate object of worship (V4)
But he has not been revealed because he is being restrained (V6)
this situation will continue until that restraint is removed which will then, obviously, reveal the man of lawlessness (V7, 8)

All this simply means that the apostacy/rebellion has not yet occurred but will occur sometime in the (then) future before the day of the Lord.
V9-11 then states that when this man of lawlessness is revealed, the great rebellion/apostacy will occur.
